# Water Package R: Arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Tags: r

Below is the code which I am trying to execute:

```
csvfile <- "june 29.csv" 
MTLfile <- "LC81450452015084LGN00_MTL.txt"
WeatherStation <- read.WSdata(WSdata = csvfile, date.format = "%d/%m/%y", lat=21.44467, long= 78.14438, elev=400, height= 2.0, MTL = MTLfile)
```

The following error comes up:

> Error in data.frame(date = unique(WSdata$date), radiation_sum = tapply(WSdata$radiation,  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

The csv file contains year as dd/mm/yyyy so I made it to YYYY in the command. Otherwise it is not even able to read the file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just changed the YYYY to Y (for year with century as per R documentation). A new error comes up: Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: Tried debugging the code workflow, it seems the error is coming up while calculating hourly data, so the by argument has "1 hour" written in the source file which cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

before joining the two dataframes, have you checked that dimensions is compatible?
Try with:

```
dim(csvfile) 
dim(MTLfile)
```

Because you can join only dataframes wich have the same dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though dim for both are coming NULL.

Comment: @fjord sorry, dim() is for data.frame or matrix, if you try with 
length(csvfile) 
length(MTLfile)
what is the results?

Comment: It is coming as [1] 1 for both.

Comment: I guess it has more to do with the rows in the csv file itself. If you could explain why the two columns are mentioned in the error unique(WSdata$date), radiation_sum = tapply(WSdata$radiation.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here `date.format = "%d/%m/%y"`

Your date format its `%d/%m/%Y`. You have to use %Y when you have year as in 2017.

If you are still having problem, please show me the first two rows of csvfile.

Cheers